# Why outgoing requests from app running on nginx not hit Kubernetes services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I deployed an application running on nginx in Kubernetes, it's a simple static `index.html`. I defined a button with a url to `http://backservice:8080/action`. `backservice` is a k8s service backing a Spring application.

The problem is, when I click on that button, nothing happens. `backservice` is not hit. I expect a `CORS` error but it seems like nginx blocks all outbound requests. I don't want to proxy the backend service into nginx.

Nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Server conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html; 

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /svg/ {
    }

    location /assets/ {
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

The `backendservice` is in the same namespace as the nginx app.

Comment: Do you get some console errors in browser?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian Yes, I have a `Status:fail`, `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static app runs in your browser. The browser isn't part of the k8s cluster so it is not aware of the URL `http://backservice:8080/action`

Expose your backend service using Ingress. For example `https://backend.example.com/action`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ 
(You can expose using Loadbalancer type too but I suggest Ingress)

Then change your frontend code to hit `https://backend.example.com/action`

Comment: `backendservice` is already accesible from outside. I would like to avoid a such round trip, I mean avoiding the nginx app from leaving the cluster to hit `backendservice`. Is it possible?

Comment: The static code runs in your browser, not on the nginx! so the action call that you are trying to make is originating from the browser and hitting the backend directly, not via the Nginx.  Since your browser is making the action and the browser is not part of the Kubernetes cluster, you can't reach the backend directly using the service name. You will need ingress or something similar setup

Comment: https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/JwIBwPsTfBmelKgSrCCkEZuTzC5Ty1pZi3K7 similar to this setup there are no round trips here

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-kubernetes-in-under-3-hours-a-detailed-guide-to-orchestrating-containers-114ff420e882/ is the article

Comment: `backendservice` is a gateway which backed several other services, the frontend app is also backed by this gateway. So to access the frontend, I defined an Ingress with default route `/*` pointing to the gateway and the gateway default route `/*` is bound to the frontend which renders the index.html. I hope you see what I mean

Comment: If your `backendservice` is forwarding requests using the service name there won't be any round trips.

Comment: Simple your frontend code is running in your browser, the only way to reach the `backendservice` is by exposing using Ingress or something similar or by port forwarding.

There are no round trips here!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but to hit `backendservice` I should set its url to the frontend, say `https://backend.example.com/`, so every time we'll call it we'll have to resolve that url, so that means leaving the cluster. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your static frontend code runs on the user's browsers, which is outside the Kubernetes cluster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198732/discussion-between-tummala-dhanvi-and-akuma8).

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that `backservice` is hostname which is resolved only inside the k8s cluster. If you want to make it accessible from the outside of the cluster it should be exposed using [ingress](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html) or [external services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/) (LoadBalancer, NodePort).

Comment: `backendservice` is already accesible from outside, I defined an Ingress for that. I would like to avoid a such round trip, I mean avoiding the nginx app from leaving the cluster to hit `backendservice`. Is it possible?

Comment: But if you are accessing your index.html from your browser, then the request to `/action` should go from outside of the cluster using ingress or whatever. There is no any roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened port 8080 on the ingress deployemnt ?

If your kubernetes is on public cloud . It should have a Load Balancer that used by Ingress nginx . You can configure that load balancer in the service of ingress deployment in kubernetes namespace kube-system

this is an example if you want to allow port 8080 on your ingress nginx to hit port 80 of your service :

kgs nginx-ingress-lb -n kube-system -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-lb
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.21.12.220
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: nginx-ingress-lb-443-443
    nodePort: 32672
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: nginx-ingress-lb-8080-80
    nodePort: 32026
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```